# O significado de "Você também não vai?"

Tags: português-brasileiro

Eu acho **Você também não vai?** como **Eu não vou e você também não vai**.

Mas eu vi no texto:

> — Você vai ao baile?
>   — Claro!
>   — Você também não vai?

Parece que está perguntando se você não vai?

Alguma explicação?

Comment: Não significa necessariamente que quem perguntou não vai para a festa. Ex: “— Adriana e Fernanda não vão à festa. Você vai? / — Claro! Você também (além de Adriana e Fernanda) não vai?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse *também* refere-se somente ao *vai*. É como dizer:

> Claro (que vou ao baile). Você não **vai também**?

Equivale a: “não é verdade que você vai também?”

Poderíamos dizer que esse *também* (do “você também não vai?”) está fora do sítio normal, mas nós falamos assim.

E o *não* é retórico: neste contexto, perguntar “você também não vai?” ou “você também vai?” dá praticamente no mesmo; a única diferença é que se eu incluir o *não* — “você também não vai?” ou “você não vai também?” — dou uma ideia que tenho a expetativa que a outra pessoa vai ao baile e quero só confirmar.

---

Realmente isto é um pouco confuso, porque nós podemos usar exatamente as mesmas palavras para perguntar o contrário; nestes caso o *não* é mesmo obrigatório:

> Ana: — Você vai ao baile?
>
> Bela: — A nossa avó morreu ontem; claro que não vou! Você também não vai... ?

Este “você também não vai” é dito quase como se fosse uma afirmação e não um pergunta. O exemplo seguinte já é perguntado com a entonação normal:

> A Bela não vai ao baile; a Ana também não. Você também não vai?

Nestes exemplos o *também* refere-se mesmo ao *não* (por isso, não podemos omitir esse *não*); — este *você também não vai* significa “é verdade que você também não vai?” Compreendemos a diferença pelo contexto: o *também* significa ’tal como a pessoa mencionada antes’: no teu exemplo, eu vou ao baile, portanto *também* quer dizer ’vai também’ (= ’tal como eu vou’); nos últimos dois exemplo, a pessoa mencionada antes não vai, portanto *também* quer dizer ’também não vai’ (= ’tal como a primeira pessoa não vai’).

Comment: Realmente, contexto e entonação fazem toda a diferença nesse uso particular da palavra "também", a qual admite várias posições na frase.